# Access External Variable from with-in Mock Script Block (Pester)

Tags: powershell, pester

Pretend I have a function like...

```
function Get-Something {
  return Get-DogShit
}
```

...in my Pester test script...

```
$var = 1

Mock 'Get-Dogshit' { return $var }

it 'should return true' {
  Get-Something | should $var
}
```

This doesn't work, but you see what I'm trying to do here? I want to get the value from a local variable into a MOCK script block. I want to avoid hard coding the return value in the mock and the expected result in the it-block. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: try `return $using:var`?

Comment: Any issues using scope with pester? `$script:var = 1` or `$global:var = 1`

Comment: Sadly, no, but that was a really good idea. I get the following when I try that: "A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, 
the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer."

Comment: @gms0ulman, those worked! I swear I tried $global before posting this, but trying them both now did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't sure if it would work as not messed with pester before but apparently it follows the same [scope rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6) as standard PowerShell.

So `$script:var = 1`, and the brute-force `$global:var = 1` if it doesn't or if you need to call it from outside the script scope.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem myself, and script scope didn't work and I didn't care to use global scope. A bit of research shows how you can use closures for this.

```bsh
$var = 1

Mock 'Get-Dogshit' { return $var }.GetNewClosure()

it 'should return true' {
  Get-Something | Should be $var
}
```

Comment: GetNewClosure() is a better option than global scope and I am not sure it is documented in Pester - https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/204, there is also InModuleScope if you want to access variables and private functions from module you are testing - https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/InModuleScope

Comment: For completeness: Having a look at scope modifiers I thought perhaps the `using` modifier might work, since it's used to allow local variables to be used with remote sessions.  However, it doesn't work in this scenario.  <ScriptBlock>.GetNewClosure() definitely does, however.